# Rails runs action with wrong controller

Tags: routes, controller, ruby-on-rails-6.1

my problem is, that when I click on a link, Rails should take the action with the respective controller and method, but instead, process the action with the wrong controller. Here is the structure of my code:

This is my link_to in the .html.erb file

```
<%= link_to modal_boxes_path, data: { image_id: img.identifier, bs_toggle: 'modal', bs_target: '#listBoxesModal', remote: :true } do%>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
<% end%>
```

This is the route in the routes.rb file

```
get '/modal_boxes', to: 'boxes#modal_boxes', as: :modal_boxes
```

So, when I click on the link, the action should be processed by the Boxes controller and modal_boxes action, but instead, Rails executes the action with "UsersController#profile".

The idea is that when I click on the link_to, a bootstrap modal has to be showed and loads the content, the modal is showed but in blank, the content should be loaded with the model_boxes action that respond to with js format and js.erb file sould load the content into the modal.

This is what Rails shows in the console when I click on the link_to

[image]

Says that is processed by JS because I also have a respond to format js in the profile action in Users controller and a in the js.erb file I render the partial where I have the link_to, but, this partial also is rendered in another view out of profile view, so this shouldn't be a problem.

I hope I'm clear on what my problem is